# Swift decoding JSON string and access a property that can be either single object or array of objects

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have the following JSON that is the API response (simplified to show where I want to grab the info):

```
{
  "Response": {
    "Output": {
      "Periods": {
        "Period": [
          {
            "Details": {
              "TDetail": [
                {
                  "std": "A1405",
                  "sta": "A1640"
                },
                {
                  "std": "A1805",
                  "sta": "A2000"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Details": {
              "TDetail": {
                "std": "A0705",
                "sta": "A1334"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used https://app.quicktype.io to construct the structs for the response:

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let event = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Event.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - Event
struct Event: Codable {
    let response: Response?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
    }
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let output: Output?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case output = "Output"
    }
}

// MARK: - Output
struct Output: Codable {
    let periods: Periods?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case periods = "Periods"
    }
}

// MARK: - Periods
struct Periods: Codable {
    let period: [Period]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case period = "Period"
    }
}

// MARK: - Period
struct Period: Codable {
    let details: Details?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case details = "Details"
    }
}

// MARK: - Details
struct Details: Codable {
    let tDetail: TDetailUnion?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tDetail = "TDetail"
    }
}

enum TDetailUnion: Codable {
    case tDetailElement(TDetailElement)
    case tDetailElementArray([TDetailElement])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([TDetailElement].self) {
            self = .tDetailElementArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(TDetailElement.self) {
            self = .tDetailElement(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(TDetailUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for TDetailUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .tDetailElement(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .tDetailElementArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - TDetailElement
struct TDetailElement: Codable {
    let std, sta: String?
}
```

I'm stuck at how to access TDeatailUnion and accessing std and sta values.

Here is the playground tests:

```
import UIKit

let jsonString = """
            {"Response":{"Output":{"Periods":{"Period":[{"Details":{"TDetail":[{"std":"A1405","sta":"A1640"},{"std":"A1805","sta":"A2000"}]}},{"Details":{"TDetail":{"std":"A0705","sta":"A1334"}}}]}}}}
"""

// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let event = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Event.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - Event
struct Event: Codable {
    let response: Response?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
    }
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let output: Output?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case output = "Output"
    }
}

// MARK: - Output
struct Output: Codable {
    let periods: Periods?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case periods = "Periods"
    }
}

// MARK: - Periods
struct Periods: Codable {
    let period: [Period]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case period = "Period"
    }
}

// MARK: - Period
struct Period: Codable {
    let details: Details?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case details = "Details"
    }
}

// MARK: - Details
struct Details: Codable {
    let tDetail: TDetailUnion?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tDetail = "TDetail"
    }
}

enum TDetailUnion: Codable {
    case tDetailElement(TDetailElement)
    case tDetailElementArray([TDetailElement])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([TDetailElement].self) {
            self = .tDetailElementArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(TDetailElement.self) {
            self = .tDetailElement(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(TDetailUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for TDetailUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .tDetailElement(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .tDetailElementArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - TDetailElement
struct TDetailElement: Codable {
    let std, sta: String?
}

// Decoding the JSON STRING
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Event.self, from: data)
let periods = response?.response?.output?.periods
/*
 I'm stuck on how to access TDetailUnion
 */
```

I checked all similar questions on stack overflow, yet they all stop on decoding, and not show how to access the elects/array.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a `enum` with associated value, use a switch of case let. But in My opinion, that `switch` is overkill, you should just have always a `[TDetailElement]`, with a single element or multiples.

Comment: @Larme thank you for reply. I tried to do switch but I'm unable to access the objects values. Could you please explain your answer more.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9qZdzwY9

Comment: I don't find the duplicate marked by vadian as relevant, since you did the decoding with an enum switch as the question. Your issue is about reading an enum with associated value. Also, in your case, it could be simplified and removed.

Comment: @Larme thank you very much for explaining thru code, now I understood what you meant with "overkill". Highly appreciated.  :)